# Compression algorithm for files smaller than 10MB with largest compression ratio

Tags: file, compression, comparison

What lossless compression algorithm can I use to compress files smaller than 10MB that delivers the largest compression ratio?

It doesn't matter if it will cost a lot of CPU cycles or memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a look at LZMA and PAQ8. LZMA is a popular algorithm with a really decent compression ratio on specific settings. It is used by 7zip and its Java and C libraries are readily accessible.

PAQ8 on the other hand, outperforms LZMA on most benchmarks that I have read (especially on http://www.maximumcompression.com) at the expense of CPU and memory. I feel like PAQ8 suits my needs more but it seems like it is still under development stages and is unstable (plus I can't find their sources so that I can implement it on C or Java)

Comment: paq8 is constantly being updated and improved, but it has little to do with stability. Basically, new models are added and small bugs that affect the compression speed are fixed.

The sources of all versions for the last 10-13 years are on the site of the PAQ8 author - http://mattmahoney.net/dc/#paq.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [xrt 3.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xwrt/files/).  Should be stable.